# how to click on element in gridview in appium using java

Tags: java

[image]

I have a list in linear layout.
I want to click on an app I am able to scroll on a page but not able to click on an app.

I am not getting any way to click item inside from gridview.

Can any body help me to solve my problem ?

Comment: Show us your efforts first.

Answer (score 0):

For example in grid, If I have 20 items in my grid but my screen is able to show only 10 items based on my screen size then in UI automator also you get only those which are available on screen. When I scroll then remaining elements will be visible in the UI automator

You can click on app even in grid view. After scroll you have to reload the driver content because when you scroll then new items will be shown and those wont be available in the previous driver content

```
WebDriver wd =  driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
boolean flag = false;
WebElement firstItem = null;
do {
    List<WebElement> allApps = wd.findElements(By.xpath("//android.widget.ListView"));

    if (firstItem.getText().equals(allApps.get(0).getText())) {
        System.out.println("Reached to end of list");
        break;
    }

    for (WebElement webElement : allApps) {
        if (webElement.getText().contains("Your App Name")) {
            webElement.click();
            flag = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    firstItem = allApps.get(0);

    if (!flag) {
        horizontalScroll();
    }
} while (!flag);
```

Try this and let me know if you face any issue

Comment: Thanks. But still i am able to click on element. error coming Failed To locate Element.

Comment: Try to debug and see exactly what is happening. Are you getting allApps just check in debugging ? If you are getting allApps then check are you comparing text with exact your app Name in the for loop

Comment: Add System.out.println(webElement.getText()); and see is it printing all app names

Comment: List list = driver.findElementsById("com.sh.market:id/gridView");
     System.out.println(list.size());
     for(int j=0;j<=list.size();j++)
     {
     ((WebElement) list.get(2)).click();
     }                                                                                                          i am using this code but its not working for me.

Comment: Are you getting size ?

Comment: Obviously you get error out of index, because the size is 1 and you are trying to click on 2 element. Try the below code  for(int j=0;j<=list.size();j++) { ((WebElement) list.get(i)).click(); }.  I think you are getting main grid view, so size is one, try to get items in that grid.

Comment: Thanks.How would i find no.of elements in a list. Please Help.

Comment: can you please share the hierarchy of ui automator after scrolling it and pointing to your grid view, so that i will tell

Comment: (0) frameLayout

Comment: try this code - WebElement   gridView = driver.findElementById("com.sh.market:id/gridView");
List list = gridView.findElements(By.xpath("*"));
for(int j=0;j<=list.size();j++) { 

WebElement appElement = list.get(i).findElments(By.xpath("com.android.TextView")).get(0);

if(appElement.getText().equalIgnoreCase("Phone Pe")) {
appElement.click();
break;
}
}

Comment: thanku so much. as i am new to appium so i didn't understand this getting so confused... Here what is (i) and not able to findElement by gridview. its giving error in eclipse.

Comment: (i) is incorrect it should be j, replace i with j and try. I am thinking that the Id you are using for grid view is correct. You can also contact me at karthikeya9vamsi@gmail.com

Comment: gridview.findElement not working.  giving error in eclipse.

Comment: Can you try this, WebElement gridView = driver.findElementById("com.sh.market:id/gridView");
   List<WebElement> list = gridView.findElements(By.xpath("*"));
   for (int j = 0; j <= list.size(); j++) {
    WebElement appElement = list.get(j).findElements(By.xpath("com.android.TextView")).get(0);
    if (appElement.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Phone Pe")) {
     appElement.click();
     break;
    }
   }

Answer (score 0):

Please find the images attched with it to find hierarchi.
(0) FrameLayout                                                                                                    (0) LinearLayout                                                                                                     (0)FrameLayout                                                                                                                                                            (0)LinearLayout                                                                                                           ViewGroup                                                                                                      (1) android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                                                      FrameLayout                                                                                                  RelativeLayout                                                                                               GridView                                                                                                                                   (0) FrameLayout                                                                                            (1) LinearLayout                                                                                                        (0) LinearLayout

[Hierarchi of gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mSXPU.jpg)

[hierarchi of webelement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7K0gZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Generally there is not resource-id for the item in GridView. So you have to use the XPath to get the element.
You can use the Appium Desktop Inspector to get the XPath.
Please refer to
http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-inspector/