# Android Appium Scroll UiAutomator ExpandableListView How will this combination work?

Tags: android, scroll, appium, expandablelistview

This piece of code is not working for ExpandableListView.

driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiScrollable(new UiSelector().resourceId(\"com.theentertainerme.entertainer:id/ex_listview_locations\")).scrollIntoView(new UiSelector().text(\"Singapore\"))");
[Please see attched screenshot for element hirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tObqA.png)

Any help! what I am doing wrong?

java-client 4.0, appium 1.5.3
Same piece of code is working for listView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for scroll try the below code

```
Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
int x = size.width / 2;
int starty = (int) (size.height * 0.5);
int endy = (int) (size.height * 0.1);
driver.swipe(x, starty, x, endy);
```

If you want to select an Item in a list then look into the below link -
[how to click on element in gridview in appium using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43361245/how-to-click-on-element-in-gridview-in-appium-using-java/43365574#43365574)

Comment: Left side of my answer you can get tick mark which is in light ash color. When you click then it becomes green

Comment: Done, thanks :) but now there is another problem, from appium 1.6.4 it is saying "swipe" is deprecated. What is the new approach introduced to handle swipe/scroll?

Comment: I didn't upgrade the appium version. If i know then i will let you know